# LINQ/EF: conceptual/mechanics of doing multiple joins that return both an entity and a computed value

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Im hoping someone can help me with a brain block I'm having about how to do multiple joins with EF that returns an entity, where one of the fields is calculated by a query.  Ive contrived a (pretty much useless) example in the hopes somebody can help me understand how this should be done.

Id like to return a list of ISPs entities from a DBContext with the "TotalUsed" property filled in by the LINQ query.  Ive successfully done the joins (trivial), and have played with grouping and sum, but cant seem to get it quite right.

The general idea to this contrived example is that NICs are connected to one and only one router, and multiple routers are connected to a single ISP each.

How to write a LINQ query that sums the bandwidth needed for each ISP, along with the other properties in that ISP?

Expected output would be a list of ISP that might look like
{{1, "foo", 52}, {2, "bar", 345}, {3, "foobar", 621}}, where the 3rd property is the summation of the BandwidthNeeded property on all NICs transitively related to ISP.

The classes:

```
public class ISP
{
   public int ISPid {get; set;}
    public int ISPName {get; set;}
    public int TotalUsed {get; set;}  // not mapped to DB -> should populate via LINQ
}

public class Router
{
    public int RouterId {get; set;}
    public string RouterName {get; set;}
    public int ISPId {get; set;} // foreign key for ISP
}  

public class Nic
{
    public int NicId { get; set; }
    public string NicLocation { get; set; }
    public int BandwidthUsed { get; set; }
    public int RouterId {get; set; }  // foreign key for router
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the TotalUsed property into a separate type, you could do this (please excuse any typos):

```
public class ISP // mapped
{
    public int ISPid {get; set;}
    public int ISPName {get; set;}
}
public class ISPWithTotalUsed : ISP // not mapped
{
    public int TotalUsed { get; set; }
}
var query = (from ISP in context.ISPs
             select new ISPWithTotalUsed
             {
                 ISPid = ISP.ISPid,
                 ISPName = ISP.ISPName,
                 TotalUsed = (from router in context.Routers
                              where router.ISPid == ISP.ISPid
                              from nic in context.Nics
                              where nic.RouterId == router.RouterId
                              select nic.BandwidthUsed).Sum()
             });
```

If you add navigation properties, it could be made somewhat more readable by removing the links on ID.

Comment: OK, Im fine separating out the TotalUsed property (Ill use AutoMapper in the real application anyway).  But I'm having a real problem understanding the query.  And Linqpad is unhappy, throws a "NotSupportedException" Unable to create a constant value of type ... Only primitive types are supported in this context.
I expected to see some kind of join or group join.
The 2 from statements - is that an implicit join in that one feeds the next maybe?
The actual reason I posted was to understand how to go about a query like this, so Im hoping for some conceptual help please?

Comment: I was assuming you were working with POCO entities, given your class definitions. Was that assumption wrong? Because classes derived from entity objects only work with POCO entities, as far as I know. The three froms do effectively perform a join; it's in the form of a 'where', but has exactly the same effect. The way I've written it, the first join is a left join, the second one an inner join. I'm asking for ISPs even if they have no routers, and EF knows it has to translate that to a left join.

Comment: BTW, if you do not care that your result objects "are" ISPs, you could drop the ISPWithTotalUsed type and get the results in an anonymous type, simply by changing "new ISPWithTotalUsed { ... }" to "new { ... }". That should work regardless of how you've set up your context.

Comment: Yes, I am using POCO entities throughout, but I Automap them when passing them out of the data access layer up to my domain objects, so Im fine with having the result be an anonymous type.
As far as the Linqpad exception, Ill try your solution in "real code" => maybe its a Linqpad limitation.
Thank you for your help on this...

Comment: I was just reading through Julie Lerman's EF book and came across a sidebar.  "A well defined query against a well defined EDM does not need JOIN". Navigation properties in combination with nesting sub-queries should be used instead".  Hmmm, I wish I had remembered reading that when I first read through her book :-)  That explains why none of the three answers I got to my question included a join.

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = new IspContext();
var groups = context.Nics.Include("Router.Isp").GroupBy(n => n.Router.ISPId).ToList();
var result = groups.Select(g => new() 
             { 
                 Key = g.Key, 
                 Name = g.FirstOrDefault().Router.Isp.IspName, 
                 Total = g.Sum(n => n.BandwithUsed)
             });
```

Does this work for you? The name thing is not pretty and you might get it all into one query. It's hard to tell if it runs faster though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - Ill definitely need some Linqpad time to understand this one.  Its funny that all 3 answers didnt use a join or group join, which is what I was sure was the basic solution :-)

Comment: It's a "hidden" join over the Router property.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var query = context.ISPS.Select(isp => new{ ISP : isp, Used : isp.Routes.Sum(r => r.Nics.Sum(n => n.BandwidthUsed))}).ToList();

var result = query.Select(item => {
   item.ISP.TotalUsed = item.Used;
   return item.ISP;
}).ToList();
```

I would hoverwer remove the TotalUsed propery from ISP and instead create a wrapper class that holds both an ISP and the TotalUsed. Then you could remove the second query. (EF will not let you contruct an entity inside an entity query).

Comment: Same as hvd's answer above, I expected to see some kind of join or group join here, but I think I see the simplicity of how you did it.  This solution assumes navigation properties (Routers for ISP, and Nics for router), correct?  So it is more or less a join - is that correct? Thank you for any additional help understanding this...

Comment: Yeah, I assumed navigational properties but when I look again I see you don't have them in your model. They should be easy to add, and hacing the navigation properties will make sure you have the correct indexes to join efficently. I'm not sure if EF will generate joins or subqueries for this though but that shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: I added navigation properties, and now all is well => thank you.  Its an important point you make that nav props will ensure indexes are created and used during the operations, I didnt consider that.